# Stripe - what subscription do I need to allow users to pay other users products like ebay

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to research stripe, where i would like to create a site like ebay so the system can allow users to register and sell there goods and allow other users to buy those goods and finally pay using a payment gate way.

What service would I need to use for me to achieve this using stripe?

I read something about stripe connect, would this be the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! Stripe Connect is indeed what you want. You can see a basic integration guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide) but I'd recommend perusing the Connect [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) in general. As this isn't really a technical question, you may want to consider reaching out to Stripe Support (https://support.stripe.com/contact/login) for further scoping discussion here.

Comment: Do sellers on the website need a stripe account? Also if they don't how would you get the bank details in order to get paid by the buyer?